# Keeping track of a field value changes and doing tasks when the value changes in a specific way

Tags: sql-server

I have to check whether a field(*Country*) value in my table(**Account**) changes and do a task. My application only writes 3 values on the *Country* field: either 0,1 or 2. When it's changing between 0 and 1, I don't want anything to happen. But when the value is changed to 2, I need to keep track of old *Country* value and account name from that **Account** table to another table(**Test**). And when the value again changes from 2 to either 0 or 1, I need to compare the updated *Country* value to the old value. If the old value and new value are not the same, then I will do my task.If both values are same nothing will be done.

For example, *AccountName* Paul had 1 on *Country* field in the **Account** table, let's say my app changed it to 2. Then I want to store paul(*UserName*) and 1(*OldCountry*) on my **Test** table. My app then changes the *Country* value to 0. Now I want to compare this *Country* field from **Account** table and *OldCountry* field from **Test** table. It'll be false and I will do my task(let's say print 1 for simplicity).

I'm a beginner in SQL language, I'm having trouble writing the code for this logic. If anyone helps me out here, I'll really appreciate it.

Comment: I suggest that you add sample table data to your question, and show us what you want.  If nothing else, it would also make your question more useful for others who might have a similar problem in the future.

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql) as a possible solution. I'm sure you can find lots of [similar questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btriggers%5D+and+%5B*sql-server*%5D) on SO regarding this.